# Inkscape - How to change the document scale without change objects scale

Tags: inkscape, scale, dimensions

I did make a draw in a document, but when I duplicate the file and scale the dimensions of the draw to resize it to other resolution I fall in a "0,46296" scale.

Now, I want to change the document (Ctrl + D) scale from "0,46296" to "1,00000" without change the size of the objects in the document.

[image]